# Parsing html using JAVA (Jsoup)

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I am facing a problem in parsing html document using jsoup (Java). The HTML I'm parsing has this format:

```
.....
<hr>
  <a name="N1"> </a> Text 1<br>
<hr>
  <a name="N2"> </a> Text 2<br>
<hr>
  <a name="N3"> </a>Text 3<br>
<hr>
  <a name="N4"> </a>
  <DIV style="margin-left: 36px">
   <div></div>
   <img src=bullet.gif alt="Bullet point"> Text
  </DIV><br>
<hr>
 <a name="X5"> </a>
 <DIV style="margin-left: 36px">
  <div></div>
  <img src=bullet.gif alt="Bullet point"> Text
 </DIV><br>
<hr>
  ...
```

I want to isolate the HTML text between two "hr" tags. I am trying this code:

```
File input = new File("C:\\Users\\page.html");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "http://example.com/");
Elements body = doc.select("body");
Elements hrs = body.select("hr");
ArrayList<String> objects = new ArrayList<String>(); 
for (Element hr : hrs) { 
  String textAfterHr = hr.nextSibling().toString();
  objects.add(textAfterHr);   
}
```

System.out.println(objects);

but the ArrayList doesn't contain what I want, I don't know how to resolve it. (Could I transform the "hr" tag to "hr"text"/hr" tags)?

Comment: What does the ArrayList contain? What is the expected output?

Comment: Are you interested only in `<a ..>` which is placed directly after `<hr>` or whole text between `<hr>`?

Comment: The ArrayList contains all the text between the two <tr> tags, @Pshemo i'm interested at the whole text between, witch i will parse to get the <a ..> or Divs

Comment: Can we assume that all `hr`s (at least the ones you are interested in) are on same nesting level? This way we could try iterating over all siblings of `hr` and combine them until we find next `hr`. When we do we put text gathered till now in list and start gathering again. But because we would be iterating through siblings this may fail if some `hr` are in other nesting levels.

Answer (score 0):

Here you get the result by reading the childrens of each hr tags. Use this for better solution.

```
ArrayList<String> objects = new ArrayList<String>(); 
Elements hrs = body.select("hr");
for(int i=0;i<hrs.size();i++){
 Element hrElm=hrs.get(i);
 Elements childrens=hrElm.children();
  for(Element child: childrens){
   String text=child.text();
   objects.add(text); 
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, IOException {
    String html = ".....\n" +
                    "<hr>\n" +
                    "  <a name=\"N1\"> </a> Text 1<br>\n" +
                    "<hr>\n" +
                    "  <a name=\"N2\"> </a> Text 2<br>\n" +
                    "<hr>\n" +
                    "  <a name=\"N3\"> </a>Text 3<br>\n" +
                    "<hr>\n" +
                    "  <a name=\"N4\"> </a>\n" +
                    "  <DIV style=\"margin-left: 36px\">\n" +
                    "   <div></div>\n" +
                    "   <img src=bullet.gif alt=\"Bullet point\"> Text\n" +
                    "  </DIV><br>\n" +
                    "<hr>\n" +
                    " <a name=\"X5\"> </a>\n" +
                    " <DIV style=\"margin-left: 36px\">\n" +
                    "  <div></div>\n" +
                    "  <img src=bullet.gif alt=\"Bullet point\"> Text\n" +
                    " </DIV><br>\n" +
                    "<hr>\n" +
                    "  ...";
    //Split your html string at each hr tag and keep the delimiter
    String [] splited = (html.split("(?=<hr>)"));
    //join it back to a string using a closing hr tag
    html = String.join("</hr>\n",splited);
    //use the jsoup xmlParser
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html,"",Parser.xmlParser());
    Elements eles = doc.select("hr");
    for(Element e : eles){
        System.out.println(e.html());
        System.out.println("-----------------------");
    }
}
```